# Argument values change on run time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Please consider the below code:

```js
function func1(a, b) {
  let args = arguments;
  console.log(args);

  return function() {
    for (let i in args) {
      console.log(args[i], a, b)
      args[i] += (a + b);
      console.log("|")
      console.log(args[i], a, b);
      console.log("end")
    }
  }
}

func1(2, 4)();
```

This give the below output

```
2 2 4
|
8 8 4
end
4 8 4
|
16 8 16
end
```

How does the value of `a, b` change here?

Comment: I'm surprised that I'm not finding a good original question to link this to.

Comment: The value of each arg is being reassigned here `args[i] += (a+b);`

Comment: Given the i values to be 0 and 1, args[0] is a and when you do  `args[0] += (a+b)` is as good as `a += (a+b)` and same happens with b when i is 1.

Answer (score 5):

In loose mode,¹ the [`arguments` pseudo-array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) has a **live link** to the formal parameters of a function. Here's a simpler example:

```js
function example(a) {
    console.log("before, a = " + a);
    ++arguments[0];
    console.log("after, a = " + a);
}

example(1);
```

As you can see, `++arguments[0]` **modified the value of `a`**.

This spooky link is removed in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), which should be used by all new code (explicitly, or by using modules):

```js
"use strict";
function example(a) {
    console.log("before, a = " + a);
    ++arguments[0];
    console.log("after, a = " + a);
}

example(1);
```

---

In a comment, you've asked:

> So even though if we clone the arguments, it still have live link to its clone?

Nothing in the code in the question clones the `arguments` object. `let args = arguments;` just points `args` at the object, it doesn't *copy* it. You start out with:

```
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
arguments:−−−−−>|    (arguments object)    |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                |   (spooky link to a, b)  |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Then `let args = arguments;` just does this:

```
             
arguments:−−+
            |   
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            +−−>|    (arguments object)    |
            |   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
            |   |   (spooky link to a, b)  |
args:−−−−−−−+   +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

It's still the same object.

If you *copy* it (just a shallow copy is fine), then you can modify the copy without affecting `a` and `b`:

```
let args = [...arguments]; // Or `= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`
```

Then you get:

```
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
arguments:−−−−−>|    (arguments object)    |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                |   (spooky link to a, b)  |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+

                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
argss:−−−−−−−−−>|          (array)         |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                | 0: value copied from `a` |
                | 1: value copied from `b` |
                +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and changes to `args` don't show in `a` and `b`.

---

¹ loose mode is often, sadly, called "sloppy" mode

Comment: So even though if we clone the arguments, it still have live link to its clone?

Comment: @GokulGokzz - Nothing in the code you've shown clones the `arguments` object. `let args = arguments;` just points `args` at the object, it doesn't *copy* it.

Comment: On deep clone, ```let args = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arguments)), the values of ```a,b  , remains the same.

Comment: @GokulGokzz - Right, but A) You don't need a deep clone, just a shallow copy (`const args = [...arguments];` or `const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`); and B) Never clone anything using a round-trip through JSON, it's lossy and slow. :-) Use a [deep cloning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
function func1(a, b) {
let args = arguments;
console.log(args);

return function () {
    for (let i in args)  // it runs 2 times
    {

        console.log(args[i], a, b)
        args[i] += (a + b);
        // first time args[0] (this is the reference to 'a') set to 2+2+4 = 8
        // second time args[1] (it is the reference to b) set to 4+8+4 = 16 
        console.log("|")
        console.log(args[i], a, b);
        console.log("end")

    }
}}func1(2, 4)();
```

args[0] refers to a
and args[0] refers to b

because args is a object
that is stored is somewhere else in browser/node environment

refer how reference acts in js using this
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hBJz2PPIVE)